# how to process varying number of timed jobs in app server

Tags: java, spring, timer, quartz-scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm using glassfish with hibernate, spring, and jpa for data coming into our system and displaying data to the customer.

However, I also have the need to have multiple jobs run every minute to calculate data based on the incoming data.

But I never know the number of jobs and they can change at any time since they're coming from the database. We have x number of customers, and each customer can have 1 to many jobs.

So what I really need to do is:

1. read from the table to get the number of jobs to run
2. run each of those jobs every minute
3. if a job is removed from the table, stop processing that job
4. if a job is added to the table, add a new job to the list.
5. each of these jobs will read from a table, do some calculations, and then write to a table with their results.

I've read up on some of the tools out there (quartz, ScheduledExecutorService etc) but does any actually provide this functionality? Or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with spring's TaskScheduler:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler

But no matter what you use you're going to have to write a non-trivial amount code to support all of this.  You'll have to support things like loading all tasks on server startup, ensuring tasks only run on one server (if the app is deployed to multiple glassshish instances), monitoring DB table for deleted users/jobs, etc.

Comment: Good point about the glassfish clustering and not running the task on more than one instance.  Not sure how to handle that.  I wanted everything to run in glassfish to use hibernate persistence unit.

Comment: One way I have handled similar situations: Each application server loads the full list.  They loop over them one at a time, and attempt to update status.  (1) update job set status=SCHEDULED where status=READY.  (2) commit.   #1 and #2 will only work for one application server, and that one gets to run that task.  This is optimistic concurrency.  You can use built in features of hibernate to accomplish the same thing: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic

Comment: I already have the version field in our DB tables and hibernate is set to use it.  So hibernate should handle that for me.